# No such column 'ProfileId' on entity 'User' when try to do SOQL query using Community Plus User

Tags: user-record

I am trying to query User record information in Community by using Community Plus user but getting following error:
No such column 'ProfileId' on entity 'User'
Any idea what specific permission my Community Plus user needs to access Profile object. I tested with System Administrator / Standard Salesforce user and it works but for Community Plus User it doesn't.

Comment: Provide more information how you are accessing profile info

Comment: I am running simple REST Query Api call on User object and it returns that INVALID_FIELD error

Comment: JRather than the profile object, I think you should set permissions for User object.

Comment: If I remove that field I am able to query successfully that's why I thought it is related to profile permissions.. How do you make sure ProfileId is accessible if you were to set permission on user object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Salesforce documentation:

**Profile**
Represents a profile, which defines a set of permissions to perform different operations, such as querying, adding, updating, or deleting information.

> Special Access Rules
>
> Customer Portal users can't access this object.
>
> Partner portal users can’t access this object.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm

Comment: ohh.. my bad I should have checked Profile object documentation .. That make sense .. Thanks man..

Comment: Thanks. If the answer is sufficient, please mark it as the best answer to close out this question @balindersingh

Comment: one quick related question though .. Is there any specific permission we need to assign if it is not accessible to other user types like any Administrative or General user paermission 
Or it is going to be accessible by default for every other Users

Comment: It is not accessible by portal/community users. It will be accessible by internal users.

Comment: nvm .. I found specific permission needed for that accessibility 'Manage Internal Users' and 'Manage External Users' thanks @DavidSchach

Comment: Test that out. Reading and editing those fields are very different things. Your question was about querying the value, which internal users can do. You won't need those permissions if you only want to view the fields as an internal user.

Comment: As I said @balindersingh if this answer was enough to set you on the right path, please mark it accepted so we can close it.

Comment: thanks .. yeah I need both Read/Edit eventually.. Reading was the first step..